# Importing SSL certificate not working on a server that does not have internet access

Tags: asp.net, windows, ssl-certificate

So I'm trying to import a SSL certificate from one windows machine to another windows machine within the same network. Neither of these servers have outside internet access. I've tried downloading the certificate from the target server through IE and importing it, and I've also tried importing the certificate manually (I have a copy of it directly from the target server). The certificate is from COMODO and COMODO is listed as a trusted provider. It's like the imported certificate just isn't being picked up.

The steps I follow to import:

1. Double-click the .cer file and Install Certificate
2. In the wizard, choose the store as the Local Computer folder under Trusted Root Certificate Authorities.
3. Restart IIS/Restart computer (this was listed as possibly being needed in another post)

Now when I point my browser to the target URL I still get the security prompt saying "There is a problem with this website's security certificate. The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority." and it makes me select "Continue to this website (not recommended)." in order to continue.

When I try to connect with a .net application to the same target URL, I get this error "System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

Now, from my local PC that's within the network but also has internet access, I can import the certificate just fine. I can point my browser to the target URL and I do not get the security warning, and I can run the .net app from my local pc without issue either. Can there be a problem with the servers not having updated lists of trusted providers? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: which cert are you putting in trusted root? your IIS cert shouldnt go there, only your issuing authority (which comodo should be there unless there are specfic directions here because its an internal system?)

Comment: I'm putting the .cer file that I download from the target server in trusted root. Where should the IIS cert go?

Comment: Sorry, I should make this clearer - I'm not trying to install a certificate in IIS to host a site through IIS. I'm trying to connect to an https URL.

Answer (score 1):

If the cert was issued from one of the trusted issuers, then your browser should automatically trust the site.

The only thing that needs to go into the trusted root store is comodo's certificate. It should be there already OR the system never received it. As part of windows updates new lists go out so ensure the authority that issued your cert is in the trusted root store (comodo XYZ - as they have several certs, ensure you are checking the correct name)